# Closure cannot implicitly capture a mutating self parameter

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase to observe event and then setting an image inside completion handler

```
FirebaseRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let _ = snapshot.value as? NSNull {
            self.img = UIImage(named:"Some-image")!
        } else {
            self.img = UIImage(named: "some-other-image")!
        }
})
```

However I am getting this error

> Closure cannot implicitly capture a mutating self parameter

I am not sure what this error is about and searching for solutions hasn't helped

Comment: In what environment do you call FirebaseRef.observeSingleEvent . Is it called within a struct?

Comment: Yes its called within a struct

Comment: This seemed to work for me:
.escapingFunction { [self] _ in self.someFunction }

Answer (score 105, accepted):

**The short version**

The type owning your call to `FirebaseRef.observeSingleEvent(of:with:)` is most likely a value type (a `struct`?), in which case a mutating context may not explicitly capture `self` in an `@escaping` closure.

The simple solution is to update your owning type to a reference once (`class`).

---

**The longer version**

The [`observeSingleEvent(of:with:)` method of Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/FIRDatabaseQuery#/c:objc(cs)FIRDatabaseQuery(im)observeSingleEventOfType:withBlock:) is declared as follows

> ```
> func observeSingleEvent(of eventType: FIRDataEventType, 
>      with block: @escaping (FIRDataSnapshot) -> Void)
> ```

The `block` closure is marked with the `@escaping` parameter attribute, which means it may escape the body of its function, and even the lifetime of `self` (in your context). Using this knowledge, we construct a more minimal example which we may analyze:

```
struct Foo {
    private func bar(with block: @escaping () -> ()) { block() }

    mutating func bax() {
        bar { print(self) } // this closure may outlive 'self'
        /* error: closure cannot implicitly capture a 
                  mutating self parameter              */
    }
}
```

Now, the error message becomes more telling, and we turn to the following evolution proposal was implemented in Swift 3:

- [SE-0035: Limiting inout capture to `@noescape` contexts](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0035-limit-inout-capture.md)

Stating [emphasis mine]:

> Capturing an `inout` parameter, **including `self` in a mutating
>   method**, becomes an error in an escapable closure literal, **unless the
>   capture is made explicit** (and thereby immutable).

Now, this is a key point. For a *value* type (e.g. `struct`), which I believe is also the case for the type that owns the call to `observeSingleEvent(...)` in your example, such an explicit capture is not possible, afaik (since we are working with a value type, and not a reference one).

The simplest solution to this issue would be making the type owning the `observeSingleEvent(...)` a reference type, e.g. a `class`, rather than a `struct`:

```
class Foo {
    init() {}
    private func bar(with block: @escaping () -> ()) { block() }

    func bax() {
        bar { print(self) }
    }
}
```

Just beware that this will capture `self` by a strong reference; depending on your context (I haven't used Firebase myself, so I wouldn't know), you might want to explicitly capture `self` weakly, e.g.

```
FirebaseRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { [weak self] (snapshot) in ...
```

Comment: Last paragraph is important. Be careful with capturing `self` in `@escape` blocks, you may end with retention cycles which may cause memory leaks. Better use `[weak self]` (or `[unowned self]` if you're sure about the block lifecycle) in all `@escape` blocks that capture `self`.

Comment: Soo, why is the problem solved with a reference type? Why is it any different?

Answer (score 42):

### Sync Solution

If you need to mutate a value type (`struct`) in a closure, that may only work synchronously, but not for async calls, if you write it like this:

```
struct Banana {
    var isPeeled = false
    mutating func peel() {
        var result =  self

        SomeService.synchronousClosure { foo in
            result.isPeeled = foo.peelingSuccess
        }

        self = result
    }
}
```

You cannot otherwise capture a "mutating self" with value types except by providing a mutable (hence `var`) copy.

### Why not Async?

The reason this does not work in async contexts is: you can still mutate `result` without compiler error, but you cannot assign the mutated result back to `self`. Still, there'll be no error, but `self` will never change because the method (`peel()`) exits before the closure is even dispatched.

To circumvent this, you may try to change your code to change the async call to synchronous execution by waiting for it to finish. While technically possible, this probably defeats the purpose of the async API you're interacting with, and you'd be better off changing your approach.

Changing `struct` to `class` is a technically sound option, but doesn't address the real problem. In our example, now being a `class Banana`, its property can be changed asynchronously who-knows-when. That will cause trouble because it's hard to understand. **You're better off writing an API handler outside the model itself and upon finished execution fetch and change the model object.** Without more context, it is hard to give a fitting example. (I assume this is model code because `self.img` is mutated in the OP's code.)

#### Adding "async anti-corruption" objects may help

I'm thinking about something among the lines of this:

- a `BananaNetworkRequestHandler` executes requests asynchronously and then reports the resulting `BananaPeelingResult` back to a `BananaStore`
- The `BananaStore` then takes the appropriate `Banana` from its inside by looking for `peelingResult.bananaID`
- Having found an object with `banana.bananaID == peelingResult.bananaID`, it then sets `banana.isPeeled = peelingResult.isPeeled`,
- finally replacing the original object with the mutated instance.

You see, from the quest to find a simple fix it can become quite involved easily, especially if the necessary changes include changing the architecture of the app.

Answer (score 16):

If someone is stumbling upon this page (from search) and you are defining a `protocol` / `protocol extension`, then it might help if you declare your `protocol` as *class bound*. Like this:

```
protocol MyProtocol: class {
   ...
}
```

Comment: I initially got around it by setting  `var _self = self and setting `_self.property`. I will try this solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this! I hope to help you.

```
struct Mutating {
    var name = "Sen Wang"

    mutating func changeName(com : @escaping () -> Void) {

        var muating = self {
            didSet {
                print("didSet")
                self = muating
            }
        }

        execute {
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 15, execute: {
                muating.name = "Wang Sen"
                com()
            })
        }
    }

    func execute(with closure: @escaping () -> ()) { closure() }
}


var m = Mutating()
print(m.name) /// Sen Wang

m.changeName {
    print(m.name) /// Wang Sen
}
```

Answer (score -18):

Another solution is to explicitly capture self (since in my case, I was in a mutating function of a protocol extension so I couldn't easily specify that this was a reference type).

So instead of this:

```
functionWithClosure(completion: { _ in
    self.property = newValue
})
```

I have this:

```
var closureSelf = self
functionWithClosure(completion: { _ in
    closureSelf.property = newValue
})
```

Which seems to have silenced the warning.

Note this does not work for value types so if self is a value type you need to be using a reference type wrapper in order for this solution to work.

Comment: Yes, but due to the nature of the value types now your `closureSelf`'s `property` will be `newValue` and your's won't change. Happy debugging.

Comment: Yeah. Does not solve the problem but breaks the code instead.