# Closure cannot implicitly capture a mutating self parameter, while using it on mutating Int method

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to create an extension for `Int`, that increments its value progressively through time. But it always gives me the error:

> Closure cannot implicitly capture a mutating self parameter

```
extension Int {

mutating func increment(_ value: Int, withDuration d: CGFloat, parent: SKNode) {
    let dx = CGFloat(value)*0.1/d
    parent.run(
        .repeat(
            .sequence([
                .run { self += Int(dx) }, //Error Here!
                .wait(forDuration: 0.1)
                ]),
            count: Int(d/0.1)
        )
    )

}

}
```

Comment: Short story: you cannot do it with a value type. Long story: [see this related Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41941810/335858).

Comment: How does this even work, "parent" shouldn't exist

Comment: @Knight0fDragon `parent` is a parameter

Comment: @Epsilon, ahh the order of parameters through me of, didn't even think to look right,  thank you for that