# Swift struct error (Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'self' is immutable) using Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, firebase

I have a custom `struct` called `myObjectHolder` and it has an array of a custom `struct` (called `myObject`) called `myArray`.

I try to fetch the data I store in `Firebase-Firesrtore` and to append it to the array (using a function that converts the `Firebase` document to `myObject`).

I try to do it like this:

```
struct myObjectHolder {
    var myArray = [myObject]()


    private func fetchMyObjects() {
        let db = Firestore.firestore().collection("myObjects").getDocuments { (querySnapshot, err) in
        for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
            self.myArray.append(self.myObjectFromDocument(document: document)) //Error
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason, when I try to append the new `myObject` to `myArray`, I receive this error message:

`Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'self' is immutable`

Does anybody know how can I resolve it? (I am using `SwiftUI` it matters)

Thank you!

Comment: You need to use a class here.

Comment: Related/duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41940994/closure-cannot-implicitly-capture-a-mutating-self-parameter

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I've just changed it from `struct` to `class` and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Use class instead of struct is one solution - and if you think struct suits your design then use

```
struct myObjectHolder {
    var myArray = [myObject]()


    private mutating func fetchMyObjects() {
        let db = Firestore.firestore().collection("myObjects").getDocuments { (querySnapshot, err) in
        for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
            self.myArray.append(self.myObjectFromDocument(document: document)) //Error
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What other have said before is correct: you cannot modify a struct, hence you should use a class - or make the struct modifiable. For more details, check out https://chris.eidhof.nl/post/structs-and-mutation-in-swift/

Since you've mentioned Firestore specifically, let me suggest you use an MVVM architecture:

Put your data access logic into a view model:

```swift
import Foundation
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

class ThingViewModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var things = [Thing]()

  private var db = Firestore.firestore()

  func fetchData() {
    db.collection("things").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
      guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
        print("No documents")
        return
      }

      self.things = documents.map { queryDocumentSnapshot -> Thing in
        return queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: Thing.self)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In your view, instantiate the view model and observe the published `things` array:

```swift
struct ThingsListView: View {
  @ObservedObject var viewModel = ThingsViewModel()

  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      List(viewModel.things) { thing in
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
          Text(thing.name)
            .font(.headline)
        }
      }
      .navigationBarTitle("Things")
      .onAppear() {
        self.viewModel.fetchData()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Also, it's good practice to use UpperCamelCase for Swift structs and classes: https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide#naming