# Mutating Struct property with asynchronous function

Tags: swift

I have the following Struct that I want to initialize, and then use its method query() to mutate its result property.

Query() sends and fetches JSON data, then decodes it to a String. When I declare query() as a mutating function, I receive the error "Escaping closure captures mutating 'self' parameter" in my URLSession.

What do I need to change?

The call:

```
var translation = Translate(string: "hello", base: "en", target: "de", result: "")
translation.query()
let translated = translation.result
```

The struct:

```
struct Translate {
    
    let string: String, base: String, target: String
    var result: String
    
    mutating func query() {
        
        let body: [String: String] = ["q": self.string, "source": self.base, "target": self.target]
        let bodyData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: body)

        guard let url = URL(string: "https://libretranslate.com/translate") else { return }
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        
        request.httpBody = bodyData
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "No data")
                return
            }
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let responseJSON = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                if let responseJSON = responseJSON as? [String: Any] {
                    if responseJSON["translatedText"] != nil {
                        self.result = responseJSON["translatedText"] as! String
                    }
                }
            }
            
            return
            
        }
        .resume()
        
    }
    
}
```

Xcode error:
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41940994/closure-cannot-implicitly-capture-a-mutating-self-parameter#:~:text=Capturing%20an%20inout%20parameter%2C%20including,explicit%20(and%20thereby%20immutable).

Comment: I read through this post, and it does help address the error, by first assigning the JSON response to a property in query() and then assigning that to the property in the Struct. However, this doesn't work asynchrounously, so the result is always nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many issues in the code.

The most significant issue is that the `URLRequest` is asynchronous. Even if no error occurred `result` will be always empty.

You have to add a completion handler – it fixes the errors you got by the way – and it's highly recommended to **handle all errors**.

Instead of `JSONSerialization` the code uses `JSONDe/Encoder`

```
struct Translation : Decodable { let translatedText : String }

struct Translate {
    
    let string: String, base: String, target: String
    
    func query(completion: @escaping (Result<String,Error>) -> Void) {
        
        let body: [String: String] = ["q": self.string, "source": self.base, "target": self.target]
        do {
            let bodyData = try JSONEncoder().encode(body)
            
            let url = URL(string: "https://libretranslate.com/translate")!
            var request = URLRequest(url: url)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            
            request.httpBody = bodyData
            request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
                if let error = error { completion(.failure(error)); return }                                       
                completion( Result{ try JSONDecoder().decode(Translation.self, from: data!).translatedText} )
            }                
            .resume()
        } catch {
            completion(.failure(error))
        }
    }
}

let translation = Translate(string: "hello", base: "en", target: "de")
translation.query() { result in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        switch result {
            case .success(let translated): print(translated)
            case .failure(let error): print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Both exclamation marks (`!`) are safe.

Comment: Be careful about calling the completion block on different threads in the error case and the success case. That can be a source of bugs. The caller might not be expecting that behaviour

Comment: @Shadowrun You're absolutely right, thanks. I edited the answer.