# Escaping autoclosure captures 'inout' parameter 'self'

Tags: swift

I've been writing a simplified version of Stack using enum types:

```
public enum Stack<Element> {
  case empty
  indirect case node(value: Element, next: Stack<Element>)

  public init(_ elements: Element...) {
    self = .empty
    elements.reversed().forEach(push)
  }

  public mutating func push(element: Element) {
    self = .node(value: element, next: self)
  }
}
```

However, I received the error below inside `init` and couldn't figure out why since `self` is a value type and forEach's body is not an escaping closure:

> Escaping autoclosure captures 'inout' parameter 'self'

When I explicitly write the method inside the body, the error in question is gone.

```
elements.reversed().forEach { push(element: $0) }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is actually the same as the [infamous "closure cannot implicitly capture a mutating self parameter"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41940994/closure-cannot-implicitly-capture-a-mutating-self-parameter) error in another guise. It is a consequence of the fact that `push` is `mutating`.

It is easy to confirm this by substituting a fake example:

```
public init(_ elements: Element...) {
    self = .empty
    elements.reversed().forEach(push)
}

public func push(element: Element) {
}
```

The only difference is that we took away the keyword `mutating`.

Comment: What is the difference between `forEach { push(element: $0) }` and `forEach(push(element:))`?

Comment: Is this a trick question? One calls a method, the other refers to a method.

Comment: No, of course it wasn't. I was trying to understand why the above code is working with the former, but not with the latter. both options aim to mutate self within a non-escaping closure.

Comment: Well, that's why I refer you to the "closure cannot implicitly capture" error. It has to do with the under-the-hood implementation when this is a struct and the method being referred to is mutating. You can look at the source if you're really interested in the gory details.